# How can I make the Ubuntu see LaTeX fonts installed through TeXLive?

Tags: fonts, texlive

I have Lubuntu 19.04 and I want it to be able to see TTF and OTF fonts installed via TeXLive.

Note that I did not install TeXLive via the package manager (for some reason it was giving me an outdated TeX distribution), but I did it through the install-tl script that is recommended in the tug.org website. As a result, LaTeX fonts are not installed in the default directories but rather in their own texlive directories, so Ubuntu does not see them by the default.

I know TeX fonts are available via the package manager, but add rather not double install them since they're already there ( and to avoid any possible conflicts).

So, is it possible to make my OS see the available TeXlive fonts?

Thanks.

Comment: In which directory exactly do those fonts reside?

Comment: They're spread over multiple directories in the TeXLive install directory, which is /usr/local/texlive/2019/....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to let fontconfig know about those directories via a configuration file.

My understanding is that you should have a file named `texlive-fontconfig.conf` somewhere in the directory tree. Otherwise it's [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive///Contents/live/texmf-var/fonts/conf/texlive-fontconfig.conf).

Create the file

```
/etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive-fonts.conf
```

and give it the contents of `texlive-fontconfig.conf`.

More reading:

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/257231/using-the-tex-live-fonts-in-xelatex